# How to put Input Text and ngMessage inside a Directive templateUrl? Is it possible?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to put the html code below inside a Angularjs Directive's `templateUrl` but I don't know how to do it right.

**My HTML to be put inside `templateUrl`**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.username.$touched && userForm.username.$invalid }">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control"
     ng-model="userForm.username"
     ng-minlength="5"
     ng-maxlength="10"
     required>

  <div class="help-block" ng-messages="userForm.username.$error" ng-if="userForm.username.$touched">
   <p ng-message="minlength">Your name is too short.</p>
   <p ng-message="maxlength">Your name is too long.</p>
   <p ng-message="required">Your name is required.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My Initial Directive**

```
app.directive('nameDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl: '/input-form/name.html'
  };
});
```

I tried it without directive and it works fine. But when I tried to put it in Directive, the error messages don't appear as they should be.

Comment: see my answer it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to surround the html content with `form` tag.

```
<form name="userForm">
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.username.$touched && userForm.username.$invalid }">

    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control"
         ng-model="username"
         ng-minlength="5"
         ng-maxlength="10"
         required>

    <div class="help-block"  ng-messages="userForm.username.$error" ng-if="userForm.username.$touched">
    <p ng-message="minlength">Your name is too short.</p>
    <p ng-message="maxlength">Your name is too long.</p>
    <p ng-message="required">Your name is required.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

inject the `ngMessages` if you haven't already

`angular.module("app",['ngMessages'])`

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/bLF3V0roCUlYO1q46jZu?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for the answer you provide. it works for me. its the exact answer what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
app.directive('nameDirective', function () {
 return {
   restrict: 'AE',
   templateUrl: '/input-form/name.html',
   transclude: true, 

 };
});
```

You'll need to use [`ng-transclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude), add `transclude: true` in your directive options, and add `ng-transclude` to your template:

```
<div ng-transclude class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.username.$touched && userForm.username.$invalid }">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control"
     ng-model="userForm.username"
     ng-minlength="5"
     ng-maxlength="10"
     required>

    <div class="help-block" ng-messages="userForm.username.$error" ng-if="userForm.username.$touched">
    <p ng-message="minlength">Your name is too short.</p>
    <p ng-message="maxlength">Your name is too long.</p>
    <p ng-message="required">Your name is required.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried `ng-transclude` but it didn't work for my problem. the answer of @sachila works for me. but thanks again for your answer. appreciated it.